# Input In Java- How does it work?

Tags: java

Hey guys, with a lot of help from you i was managed to write this nice code (I'm new in it, so kind of exciting.. :) )
And still I have not understand how can I  input  this code.
first of all, I get an this error in the console line (I'm using Eclipse):
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at NumberConverter.main(NumberConverter.java:5).
What does that mean?

I just want to chack whether it works, and I can't call the function/program any how.
I used to call in an "old fashion way", like in scheme, to the function that I wrote and see if something happens. How does it work in java? Do we call the program itself? function? what and where do we write? -I want to chack if it works, doesn't matter how, and I'll be glad to know how can I plugin input.
Thank you so much!

```
public class NumberConverter{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       toBinary(i);
       toOctal(i);
       toHex(i);
   }

   public static void toBinary(int int1){
       System.out.println(int1 + " in binary is");
       System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(int1));
   }
   public static void toOctal(int int1){
       System.out.println(int1 + " in octal is");
       System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(int1));
   }

   public static void toHex(int int1){
       System.out.println(int1 + " in hex is");
       System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(int1));
   }
```

}

Comment: you need to pass command line arguments in Eclipse. You can do this via run configuration in the `NumberConverter` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set arguments for app start up. You can do this in Run Configuration editor (Right click on project -> Run as.. -> Run Configurations). In Arguments tab you can put one to program Arguments field. One argument per line (eg. 5).

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs because of empty `args` array that you want to take first element of empty array - `args[0]`. You can't do this because the array is empty if no app start up arguments are set.

Comment: Hi michal, what exactly do I do in the Arguments tab? Thanks.

Comment: You have to click to Program arguments field and write eg. 5. This value will be passed to `args`.  Then you access it throught `args` . So `args[0]` will contain "5".

Answer (score 4):

It means there was an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) at line 5 of `NumberConverter`.  This is most likely going to be this line (if the full source contains a package statement followed by a blank line, this will be line 5):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Which tries to access the first argument you passes to the program, since you did not pass any arguments to the program the arbs array is empty and attempts to access `args[0]` results in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

If you were running this from the command line you it should look something like this:

```
$ java com.mypackage.NumberConverter 1
```

Here `$` is the prompt, `com.mypackage` is presumed to be the package name and `1` is the command line argument which you will be able to access via  args[0]`.

Since you are using eclipse and not via a command line [here is a nice blog post](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/java-se/java-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse-ide.html) on adding command line arguments from within eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) means (from JavaDoc):

> Thrown to indicate that an array has
>   been accessed with an illegal index.
>   The index is either negative or
>   greater than or equal to the size of
>   the array.

From your exception, `args[0]` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` because `0` is greater than or equal to `args.length`. My suggestion is to find out what arguments is the OS returning to your JVM which is then passed to your app and see if `args[0]` is initialized and populated.

Also, running a program from Eclipse requires you to set arguments through `Run Configurations`.

Answer (score 1):

an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you try to access an index outside of an array. Let's say that I have an array of size 2. I can access the first and second elements using the indices 0 and 1 respectively, but if I try to access the element in index 4, an exception is thrown:

```
public static void stam() {
    int[] array = { 0, 1 };
    // this will print 0
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    // this will print 1
    System.out.println(array[1]);

    // this will crash the program
    System.out.println(array[4]);
}
```

Your instinct was correct that you can easily test your program using input, although using a literal value and a variable are probably an easier, and certainly more flexible option. In any case, you can set up the run configuration to include command line arguments via the `Run > Run Configurations...` window.

As you probably guessed, the reason why your program was crashing is because you try to access the first command line argument in line 5 of your class, but the argument wasn't there, so the array has 0 elements.

A slightly more flexible way of running a java program with command line arguments is by calling the main method of a different class, and manually passing it a String array. But if you want to test your methods quickly, just pass them literal values.