# Can't open an image because of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Have made this program that should open an image on my desktop but it gives me the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I run it. What I done wrong?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class Image {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    new Image(args[0]);
}

public Image(final String filename) throws Exception
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            JFrame editorFrame = new JFrame("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/index.jpg");
            editorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            BufferedImage image = null;
            try
            {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
            editorFrame.getContentPane().add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            editorFrame.pack();
            editorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            editorFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

What do I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Image.main(Image.java:15)
```

Comment: Have you passed in any parameters?

Comment: It seems that you don’t pass an argument when running the program.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input In Java- How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207406/input-in-java-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass command line argument to `main()` method. That argument we are passing through `Image()` constructor.

```
new Image(args[0]);
```

Please take a look on Command Line concept below.

**What is Command Line Argument?**

> A Java application can accept any number of arguments from the command
>   line. Those arguments called as Command Line Arguments. This allows the user to specify configuration information when
>   the application is launched.

**How to pass command line arguments?**

> The user enters command-line arguments when invoking the application
>   and specifies them after the name of the class to be run.

For example,
suppose a Java application called Sort sorts lines in a file. To sort the data in a file named friends.txt, a user would enter:

```
java Sort friends.txt
```

Here: **Sort**-- classname
      **friends.txt** --- command line argument.

> When an application is launched, the runtime system passes the
>   command-line arguments to the application's main method via an array
>   of Strings. In the previous example, the command-line arguments passed
>   to the Sort application in an array that contains a single String:
>   "friends.txt".

**Update**:

You can pass multiple command line argument with Space as a delimiter.

like

```
java Sort stack.txt overflow.txt
```

**How to pass Command line Arguments in Eclipse ?**

Go to program on package explorer or Navigator view

Select that program ---> after that right click on program select  **Run As** ---> **Run Configuration** ---> select **Arguments** second option on top ---> give arguments on **Program Arguments**

See the below Screen Shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look like you forget to pass the comand line args.

```
new Image(args[0]);
```

Comment: Where do I have to do that?

Comment: When you are running your app. See the answer from @Anil .
If you are running your app from IDE it depends which IDE you are using. Think you can google how to pass command line arguments in your particular IDE.

Comment: Did you tried to google a little? I found this info in 1 min.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments

Comment: `new Image(args[0]="C:/Users/Username/Desktop/index.jpg");`

Comment: This line isn't executed, you application crashed before this line. On line 15. You should follow the instructions described in the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646719/eclipse-command-line-arguments

And pass your args.